# stop iterating after returning a true?

Tags: c#, iteration

(couldn't think of a better title, feel free to edit it to a title that describes the question better)

I have the following method:

```
bool CalculateNewState(int adjacent, bool currentState)
    {
        if (currentState == true)
        {
            foreach (int n in liveRule)
            {
                if (adjacent == n)
                {
                    return true;
                }               
            }
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (int n in becomeAliveRule)
            {
                if (adjacent == n)
                {
                    return true;
                }               
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

This is for a [game of life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) clone. What I want to implement is that a user can make his own rules.

The `bool currentState` tells the method whether the cell is alive or not. the `int adjacent` tells the method how many alive neighbors the cell has.

What I want to achieve with this is that when the user says:
`2,3 and 5 neighbors keep the cell alive`. That it will iterate through an array (`liveRule`) that holds `2,3 and 5`. when any match occurs it should return `true`, else `false`.

What happens here is that, after returning a true, it keeps iterating and will eventually return whether the last element in `liveRule` matched.

What do I need to do, to stop iterating after a match has occurred?

It is of course possible I'm taking the wrong approach to this problem. I started from the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8911405/dynamic-if-statement).

(tried to describe it to the best of my abilities, but it still seems quite unclear)

This is C# in Unity3D.

Comment: "What happens here is that, after returning a true, it keeps iterating" - are you *sure* that's what's happening?

Comment: I'll do a double check, but I'm quite sure that's what is happening.

Comment: once you reach a `return` statement you will leave the method's scope and there is no way that `foreach` will continue iterating. If this is what you think you are experiencing, I suspect the bug is elsewhere than in this method...

Comment: The loop logic is indeed suspect and you should fix it. There are other improvements you could make. Start by renaming "currentState" to "isAlive". Booleans should answer a true/false question. We don't know whether "currentState" being true means alive or dead. It will make the code less confusing. Then, rather than saying `if(isAlive==true)` just say `if(isAlive)` -- it reads more nicely.

Comment: @AakashM Checked it again, and the iteration seems to work now. The result isn't correct though.

Comment: @Eric +1 for boolean naming convention

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you've implemented says "if adjacent is unequal to any of 2, 3 or 5, then return".  Obviously adjacent cannot be equal to *all* of them!

Start over. Rename your methods so that they are more clear. Booleans should answer a true/false question, so choose names that ask a question:

```
bool IsCellAlive(int adjacentCount, bool isAlive)
{
    if (isAlive)
        return liveRule.Contains(adjacentCount);
    else
        return deadRule.Contains(adjacentCount);
}
```

"Contains" is slower than a foreach loop, so this might cause a performance problem. Don't worry about it for now; you haven't even got the code *correct* yet. Write the code so that it is *obviously correct*, and then use a profiler to find the slow spot if it is not fast enough.

Remember: make it correct, then make it clear, then make it fast.

Comment: Thank you for the explaining the naming! (this is something we didn't learn at school yet). I tried your solution, and it appears no `Contains` method exists.

Comment: @SimonVerbeke: Put a `using System.Linq;` at the top of your program. And use C# 3 or better.

Comment: That IS recognized :) It didn't help, so I continued debugging, and noticed I was assigning the return value to the wrong array (grid, instead of newGrid). Again, a stupid mistake... Thanks!

Comment: @SimonVerbeke: Yep, the answer to the question is usually "you should continue debugging until you figure it out". :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your `return` statements will exit the `CalculateNewState` method immediately. If you find that the iteration is continuing, either you are not hitting the `return` statements (`adjacent == n` is never true), or possibly `CalculateNewState` is being called repeatedly from elsewhere in your code.

You can probably rewrite it much more simply to something like:

```
if (currentState)
    return liveRule.Contains(adjacent);
return becomeAliveRule.Contains(adjacent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can always use a "[break](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/adbctzc4%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)" statement to terminate the loop. Do something like:

```
bool CalculateNewState(int adjacent, bool currentState)
{
    if(currentState)
    {
        return IsStateMatch(adjacent, liveRule);
    }
    else
    {
        return IsStateMatch(adjacent, becomeAliveRule);
    }
}

bool IsStateMatch(int adjacent, int[] rules)
{
    bool finalState = false;

    if(rules != null)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < rules.length; i++)
        {
            if(adjacent == rules[i])
            {
                finalState = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return finalState;
}
```

I broke down the methods a little more, just for readability, but I think this is the basic idea. Now, I do agree with the other posters about what could be happening. If your loop is continuing after a break / return statement, then you most likely have buggy code elsewhere incorrectly calling the method.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your equality test is the culprit... shouldn't you be testing `adjacent == n` instead of `adjacent != n`?  That way it will return true for the matches and only return false if no match.

The iterator will NOT continue after a return exits the loop.

Comment: That was an error I accidentally left in when copying. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a for loop instead of foreach with an additional variable?

```
bool CalculateNewState(int adjacent, bool currentState)
{
    if (currentState == true)
    {
        bool match = false;
        for(int n = 0; n < liveRule.length && !match; n++)
        {
            if (adjacent != n)
            {
                match = true;
            }               
        }
        return match;
    }
    else
    {
        bool match = false;
        for(int n = 0; n < becomeAliveRule.length && !match; n++)
        {
            if (adjacent != n)
            {
                match = true;
            }               
        }
        return match;
    }
}
```